# Having issues binding combobox item source from an observable collection

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, observablecollection

I am working on a uwp app and the issue is that combobox is empty with no elements, I am also open for better ideas to do that (basically need the items of the combobox being between 1 and 24). I have also used the proper using for the observable collection in the c# page.

XAML
`<ComboBox x:Name="HoursCB" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{x:Bind HoursCollection}"/>`

C#

````
public ObservableCollection<int> HoursCollection = new ObservableCollection<int>();

        public void AddHours()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 24; i++)
            {
                HoursCollection.Add(i);
            }            
        }```
````

Comment: Do you encounter any binding-errors in the debug-output when running your app? Maybe this has something to do with incorrect `DataContext`s?

Comment: No, the debug output of my app is fine

Comment: Hello @MarcAnt01 , this code looks fine, but what needs to be confirmed is that the `AddHours` method is actually called? I ran a simple test, and it works fine (I called the `AddHours` method in the page constructor).

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to call the method, sorry. Thanks for making me notice that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need a method. Just initialize the collection directly:

```
public ObservableCollection<int> HoursCollection = 
    new ObservableCollection<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 24));
```